# Will I get punished for having gay thoughts?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, sin, forgiveness, makruh

I know that being gay in Islam is a very major sin and I would never let my self fall into doing this and engaging into this act no matter what my feeling and desire tell me. What I want to know if I have gay thoughts purposely or unintentionally will I get punished for it. Also I would like to mention I don’t have these thoughts about everyone who’s the same gender as me but just one particular person. And that’s how I know I’m not really gay.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about bad thoughts is sinning, but this ummah is forgiven from it's bad thoughts as long as it does not speak of its thoughts, or act upon it.

(Sahih bukhari 6664)

Answer (score -1):

everyone thinks things you wouldn't get sent to prison for thinking about killing someone though you would be watched more carefully i like to think the same will apply to your situation as long as you dont commit any sins your golden most of the time

- mr.H